# Windows 10 stuck in diagnostics loop

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader, sony-vaio, diagnostic

Laptop : Sony vaio Model number : SVF152125NB Running O.S : dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu)

After the last update (probably at June 2018, I don't remember the exact update name/ID) from Windows, my pc is stuck in the Infinite loop of "diagnosing your PC ".

I tried with going into recovery mode but using that method also ends up in this loop.

After this issue I am using Ubuntu by using force shut down method. And turn on which results in grub option.

Anyone pls suggest me the solution !!

Comment: What exactly was the "last update"?  Please provide the specifics of the updates that were installed and update your question.

Comment: Most fixes for such problems involve repairing Windows using a boot DVD/USB. This will perhaps destroy grub and you will need to reinstall it.

Comment: @harrymc by using dvd/USB repair, will my data be erased or retained? And which repair ISO file of Windows should I use? Since my Windows 10 is genuine and I don't have repair dvd with me? Thanks in advnc

Comment: You may do the repair from boot and it will not destroy the data. Even if you are required to re-install, Windows will not destroy anything if it manages to discover the existing installation and only do an "upgrade". If this interests you I can put up an answer, but I would need to know if Windows & Ubuntu are on separate disks or one disk with separate partitions.

Comment: @harrymc Ubuntu is in a partition of different disk

Answer (score 2):

Windows 11 Pro, HP Desktop. I ticked on Diagnostics Startup, I rebooted and my computer went into a loop on desktop screen, could not do any thing, could not start msconfig. Rebooted many times with same results.  I saw a post to hold shift key and tap F8. I got the loop to stop but I had no task bar, but by luck I had several folder shortcut's on my desktop, by clicking on one I was able to get into file explorer and go to Windows>System32 and scroll down to msconfig and I clicked on it and it opened.  It still had Diagnostics Startup ticked, I unticked it and rebooted normally. Must be a bug in the system.

Answer (score 1):

You need a
[Bootable USB Recovery Drive](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4200-create-recovery-drive-windows-10-a.html)
or a
[Bootable Windows installation USB](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html).

It would be much simpler if you have another working Windows computer
(which I will assume you have).

**Backup your data**

Use Ubuntu to save your data. Take also an image of the Windows partition.
You might use for that the boot CD/USB of
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html),
since it will only save used sectors, so the saved image will be much
smaller than the entire partition.

**Method 1 : Disable Automatic Repair using the Command Prompt**

- Boot from the boot media
- Select your language preferences, and click on Next.
- Click on Repair your computer.
- Click on Troubleshoot.
- Click on Advanced Options.
- Click on Command Prompt.
- Run the command:

  ```
  bcdedit /set {current} recoveryenabled No
  ```
- Let windows do any automatic repairs
- Type exit and press Enter.

**Method 2 : System Restore**

- Boot again into Advanced Options
- Click Troubleshoot
- Click Advanced Options
- Click System Restore and see if you can go back to an earlier time before
  the problem occurred.

**Method 3 : Repair Install**

- Boot again into Advanced Options
- Click Startup Repair

You should at this stage be prompted to select the a Windows version to repair.
If you are not prompted, try to navigate the installation to the same partition
where Windows was previously installed and see if it recognizes it as a
Windows installation.
If it does not recognize it, stop, since by installing you would lose
everything.